# Why common mode filters are usually found on AC input stage and not the output stage of an isolated smps?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, emi-filtering, common-mode-choke

Title explains the question, I believe.

Comment: What do you think the filters are filtering?

Comment: The output stage of an SMPS **is** filtered, there are almost always one or more **smoothing capacitors** present which also act as a filter. Also many SMPSs have a **ferrite bead** around the output wire, also that is a filter.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yes I know ferrite beads and capacitors are used at the output stage, I'm asking why specifically are not common mode filters are not used instead of ferrite beads at the output.

Comment: @Transistor to prevent EM noise from leaking out.

Comment: Usually because of no requirements on the DC side for 150 kHz-30 MHz on most products. Battery chargers is an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For differential noise, the DC output is easily filtered by the internal reservoir capacitor on the output. The output common mode noise can be trickier.

That CM noise mainly comes from capacitive coupling between SMPS transformer primary and secondary. The leakage capacitance might be in the order of 100 pF and, this can mean that there is a lot of switching CM noise on the DC output. This can be removed by using a common-mode filter but, only if the SMPS has access to an earth point allowing the CM capacitors to shunt the noise away.

On smaller SMPSs that don't have an earth connection (i.e. that vast majority), the problem is "solved" by a Y capacitor from the DC output to the rectified mains DC bus. This is usually in the region of a couple of nF: -

[image]

It's not ideal but, it's a numbers game and "good-enough to meet EMC requirements" is "good-enough for most folk".

[Link to another answer about this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/453763/y-cap-between-ac-ground-and-dc-ground-in-smps/453768#453768)

[Another link to same issue](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/268597/coupling-between-hot-ground-and-cold-ground/268602#268602)

Regarding the input side of the SMPS, if an earth connection isn't used, any filter can only reduce differential noise from getting onto the AC mains. Note L1 and CX1 on the circuit above.

If there **is** an earth wire than it's likely that the SMPS power output is significantly more than a conventional wall-wart and then, a CM filter will be needed. Given that in these circumstances the CM noise on the DC output might also be excessive (more power = more noise usually), a CM filter might also be required there (and make use of the earth wire).

Answer (score 2):

In an SMPS high frequency (around 20 kHz to 300 kHz) **switching** is used to convert the electrical power. Using a higher frequency than 50 or 60 Hz means that the transformer can be smaller, more efficient and cheaper.

This switching is done as fast as possible, the time between switching a transistor from on to off (and off to on) should be as short as possible to ensure good efficiency. This unfortunately results in lots of **high frequency noise** to be produced. This switching noise can disturb other equipment.

It must be prevented that this noise will enter the mains lines as that would act as a giant antenna and also allows the noise to reach other equipment and disturb these.

So filtering is used to prevent the switching noise from reaching the mains. Without filtering it will be difficult, even impossible to meet [EMI requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference).

The output stage of an SMPS **is** filtered, there are almost always one or more **smoothing capacitors** present which also act as a filter.

Also many SMPSs have a **[ferrite bead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead)** around the output wire, also that is a filter.

Common mode filters are used at the AC side of an SMPS because that is the most effective way to filter the switching noise as that signal is mainly a common mode content signal with almost no differential part. A common mode filter will use the signal itself to cancel it out. That is more effective (gives a higher suppression of the noise) than filtering using only inductors and capacitors.

Some SMPSs do use common mode filtering at the output side but these supplies are rare. Very likely the smoothing capacitors combined with a ferrite bead gives enough suppression already. Also note that the transformer is present between output side and the switching transistors. The transformer also filters out part of the switching noise.

Comment: I'm asking why specifically are not common mode filters are not used instead of ferrite beads at the output.